# ASP.NET MVC - edit in modal

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, crud

I'm trying to make an edit in a modal.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.DataList)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectName)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Attachment.Name)</td>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="editData(@item.ID,'EditModal')" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a></td>               

        <input type="hidden" value="@item.ID | @item.ProjectName | @item.Material.MaterialName " id="@item.ID" />
    </tr>
}
```

And this is working without `@item.Material.MaterialName`. With this model I got this error:

> Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Attachment.Name)

Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

I tried:

```
<td>
    @if (item.Attachment != null)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Attachment.FileName)
    }
</td>
```

and:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@item.ID | @item.ProjectName | @item.Material.MaterialName | @item.Attachment.Name " id="@item.ID" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw  your comment  at 
"And this is working without @item.Material.MaterialName"
above line indicate that your model which you bind it from action method having material as null value so you are trying to access NUll values data & which is going to give you error which you mentioned below to that line. 
try using following things wherever you want to use the properties which might be null 
@item.Material?.MaterialName & also make sure you are declaring properties are nullable in parent class .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right - attachment is null, therefore Name is also null.
I just don't understand why without a line: @item.Material.MaterialName in input error  does not appear in line: <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Attachment.Name)</td>. How does adding this line affect the appearance of an error?

Comment: HI @VMG Material class is  Not Nullable so each time when we create object instance of parent object new value shouldn't be assigned by it . Where as Assignment class is getting assigned value as it is NULLABLE . You need to read more here   https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/nullable-reference-types-in-csharp/